# Are there better patterns in Angular 1.3 for calling a function every time an item in ng-repeat is modified?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now we're using this pattern for dynamically updating models in our angular app. It works well enough, but I don't like having to repeat the ng-change all the time. Not the end of the world, but I wanted to see if there was a better pattern that I wasn't aware of.

I've looked in to $watch and $watchCollection, but I am not aware of their performance implications when watching large numbers of objects, and it also seems like the watches would then be duplicated between any manual $watch/$watchCollection and the watches that ng-repeat creates. The $watch stuff also seems to be lower level as it gives you back properties or arrays that changed, rather than just dealing with the model.

Are we just missing a better pattern, or is this currently the simplest way of dealing with this scenario?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <input type="text" ng-model="item.fooBar" ng-change="saveItem(item)>
   <input type="tel" ng-model="item.someOtherField" ng-change="saveItem(item)>
</div>

function Controller($scope){
   $scope.items = [{fooBar: "test", someOtherField:123}]
   $scope.saveItem = function(item){
      doStuffToSaveItem(item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your current solution is the simplest and most elegant one, and if you don't have any performance issues I wouldn't really worry about it.

However, one approach that would most likely be faster would be to skip adding ng-change to every input field and have a custom directive on a parent element listening for a change event on any of its children. I created an [example what it could look like](http://jsfiddle.net/9nrccnf5/).

**Note:** The change event will not trigger as you type, only when the input has lost focus.

Basically, we have a directive called on-child-change, which takes an expression as value. The directive will listen for a change event on a child, and when it detects one it will run the expression. The expression can reference `childScope`, which will be the input field´s own scope (which in turn contains the item object for that input).

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" on-child-change="onChildChange(childScope)">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="Item">
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.fooBar" />
        <input type="tel" ng-model="item.someOtherField" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.directive('onChildChange', function ($parse) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var changeExpression = $parse(attrs.onChildChange);
            element.change(function (event) {
                changeExpression(scope, {
                    childScope: angular.element(event.target).scope()
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

It could probably be improved further, but I hope the general idea comes across. Again, I would measure and only do optimizations like this if it's really needed.